# DateTimes are not formatted for Xamarin MobileServiceClient PullAsync

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I am trying to do offline sync with a Xamarin app generated through the templates in Visual Studio.  The sync worked until I added DateTime fields.  It seems the DateTime is interpreted incorrectly by the Xamarin code or Sqlite.  This is certainly an issue of properly interpreting the DateTime value sent from the server, but how can that be addressed? I am new to Xamarin and Sqlite, so I'm confused where the issue may be.  The issue occurs during the line

```
await ClientServiceManager.ClientServiceManagerDefault.InspectionsTable.PullAsync("allInspections", _inspectionsTable.CreateQuery());
```

running, but since this is buried in the class library, I can't step through to debug.

The data looks ok in the database (see highlighted CreatedDate for example):
[image: Server Database]

Fiddler reports the following json sent to the mobile app:

[image]

The Sqllite database table generated by the datastore looks like this:
[image]

After syncing, the data is not readable in the Sqlite database if you try to query it using `select id, createddate from inspection`:

```
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

If I run the query `select id, cast(createddate as text) from inspection`, the result value shown for createddate is 1525165956.457.

The sync is triggered through a call to PullAsync seen below:

```
    public class ClientServiceManager
{
    IMobileServiceSyncTable<InspectionItem> _inspectionItemsTable;
    IMobileServiceSyncTable<Inspection> _inspectionsTable;
    MobileServiceClient _client;

    public MobileServiceClient CurrentClient
    {
        get { return _client; }
    }

    public static ClientServiceManager ClientServiceManagerDefault { get; set; } = new ClientServiceManager();

    public IMobileServiceSyncTable<InspectionItem> InspectionItemsTable
    {
        get { return _inspectionItemsTable; }
    }

    public IMobileServiceSyncTable<Inspection> InspectionsTable
    {
        get { return _inspectionsTable; }
    }

    public ClientServiceManager()
    {
        _client = new MobileServiceClient(App.AzureMobileAppUrl)
        {
            SerializerSettings = new MobileServiceJsonSerializerSettings
            {
                CamelCasePropertyNames = true
            }
        };

        var path = Path.Combine(MobileServiceClient.DefaultDatabasePath, "syncstore.db");
        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);

        store.DefineTable<Inspection>();
        store.DefineTable<InspectionItem>();

        _client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, new MobileServiceSyncHandler());

        _inspectionItemsTable = _client.GetSyncTable<InspectionItem>();
        _inspectionsTable = _client.GetSyncTable<Inspection>();
    }

    public async Task<bool> SyncAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"SyncAsync called. Need to sync {_client.SyncContext.PendingOperations} changes.");

            //Pull server table changes to local tables.
            await ClientServiceManager.ClientServiceManagerDefault.InspectionsTable.PullAsync("allInspections", _inspectionsTable.CreateQuery());
            await ClientServiceManager.ClientServiceManagerDefault.InspectionItemsTable.PullAsync("allInspectionItems", _inspectionItemsTable.CreateQuery());

            //Push all context changes to the server.
            await _client.SyncContext.PushAsync();
        }
        catch (MobileServicePushFailedException exc)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"MobileServicePushFailedException occurred.  Inner exception: {exc.InnerException}");

            if (exc.PushResult == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to sync, which is alright since we have offline capabilities: {exc.Message}");

                return false;
            }
            foreach (var error in exc.PushResult.Errors)
            {
                if (error.OperationKind == MobileServiceTableOperationKind.Update && error.Result != null)
                {
                    //Update failed, reverting to server's copy.
                    await error.CancelAndUpdateItemAsync(error.Result);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Discard local change.
                    await error.CancelAndDiscardItemAsync();
                }

                Debug.WriteLine($"Error executing sync operation. Item: {error.TableName} ({error.Item["id"]}). Operation discarded.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to sync items: {ex.Message}");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Also, the entity table is based upon this class, where you see the data types used:

```
using System;

#if SERVICE
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Tables;
#endif

namespace Abc.Base.Models
{
    // The model class files are shared between the mobile and service projects.
    public abstract class EntityData
#if SERVICE
        : ITableData
#endif
    {
        #region ITableData Properties

        public string Id { get; set; }
#if SERVICE
        public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.Now;

        public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.Now;

        public bool Deleted { get; set; }

        public byte[] Version { get; set; }
#endif
        #endregion

        public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, pullasync is working okay.  I kept inspecting the SQLite table using the Visual Studio plug-in "SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox, and it throws an error when trying to render a DateTime column with a DateTimeOffset value.  I installed "DB Browser for SQLite" (http://sqlitebrowser.org/) and can see the DateTimeOffset values okay when inspecting the table, although they're rendered as a number, not a pretty date and time.